# How do I make my dates markers in matplotlib like in CSV data?

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, time

I am a noob and I made the script which takes latest CSV and plots a graph with matplotlib. But my dates are showing hours, minutes, seconds and i guess milliseconds. In CSV though, I have years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds. How do I adjust my code in the easiest and noob-friendly manner to show the dates as in CSV?

Python script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from csv import reader
from dateutil import parser
import os
import time
import pylab
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
os.chdir('/home/pi/csvdata')

def plotloop():
    for plotinsideloop in range(24):
        dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) 
            for fn in os.listdir("/home/pi/csvdata") if fn.lower().endswith('.csv')]
        dated_files.sort()
        dated_files.reverse()
        newest = dated_files[0][1]
        with open(newest) as f:
            data = list(reader(f))
        humidity = [i[1] for i in data]
        dates1 = [i[0] for i in data]
        dates = [datetime.strptime(i, '%X %x') for i in dates1]
        pyplot.ylim(50,1000)
        pyplot.xticks(rotation=15)
        pyplot.plot(dates, humidity)
        pyplot.savefig("test.png", dpi=72)
        pyplot.savefig("test.pdf")
        print ("Done")
        print(newest)
        time.sleep(5)
plotloop()
```

My csv data:

```
3/19/2017 12:01 593
3/19/2017 12:01 593
3/19/2017 12:01 594
3/19/2017 12:01 593
3/19/2017 12:01 593
```

My graph:

[image]

CSV screenshot in Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably so set up the date format directly. For that you need to add the following just before your plot command:

```
pyplot.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%x %H:%M"))
```

You will also need to change your imports a bit from

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
```

to

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.dates
```

That is needed because though you were already importing dates from matplotlib, you also later define a list called dates as well.

So in way of explanation, the function `gca()` gives you access to the Axes object. With that you can do a whole lot of stuff. See http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes

Comment: Thanks. This is my working code if anyone needs it someday http://pastebin.com/NfWmyffQ